# listview tiles not showing images (.NET2.0 , VB , winforms)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview, image

Im trying to fill a listview(tiles) with posters and titles of a DVD collection but only the titles become vissible.

this is my code:

```
Private Sub fillListView(ByVal listView As System.Windows.Forms.ListView, ByVal col As Collection)
listView.Items.Clear()
myImageList = New ImageList()
For Each item As bsDVD In col
  Try
    myImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath & item.PosterURL))
  Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.message)
  End Try
Next
myImageList.ImageSize = New Size(32, 32)
listView.LargeImageList = myImageList
For Each item As bsDVD In col
  listView.Items.Add(item.Titel)
Next
End Sub
```

Tried a lot cant get it working:(. Did i make a stupid mistake or? hope someone can help me.

ty in advance

---

ty both for helping me out...

solution code:

```
Private Sub fillListView(ByVal listView As System.Windows.Forms.ListView, ByVal col As Collection)
listView.Items.Clear()
myImageList = New ImageList()
myImageList.ImageSize = New Size(70, 100)
myImageList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth24Bit

For Each item As bsDVD In col
  Try
    myImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath & item.PosterURL))
  Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Kan afbeelding niet inladen!")
  End Try
Next
listView.LargeImageList = myImageList
Dim mItem As bsDVD
For i As Integer = 1 To col.Count
  mItem = CType(col.Item(i), bsDVD)
  listView.Items.Add(mItem.Titel)
  listView.Items(i - 1).ImageIndex = (i - 1)
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the imageindex of the listviewitem.

```
var lvitem = ListView.Items.Add(item.Titel) 
lvItem.imageIndex = 1
```

or

```
ListView.Items.Add(item.Titel,1)
```

The Xth item gets imageindex = x-1

Also, when viewmode is details, you might need to set the other Images property (SmallImageList).